# How to replace $.browser.webkit in jquery 1.9 +?

Tags: jquery

I have a code in bootstrap.js (from twitter)

```
!function( $ ) {

  $(function () {

    "use strict"

    /* CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (https://gist.github.com/373874)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     * ======================================================= */

    $.support.transition = (function () {
      var thisBody = document.body || document.documentElement
        , thisStyle = thisBody.style
        , support = thisStyle.transition !== undefined || thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MsTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.OTransition !== undefined

      return support && {
        end: (function () {
          var transitionEnd = "TransitionEnd"
          if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
            transitionEnd = "webkitTransitionEnd"
          } else if ( $.browser.mozilla ) {
            transitionEnd = "transitionend"
          } else if ( $.browser.opera ) {
            transitionEnd = "oTransitionEnd"
          }
          return transitionEnd
        }())
      }
    })()

  })

}( window.jQuery );
```

However, $.browser is removed from jquery 1.9 apparently..

How can I recode this snippet?

The doc says to use [$.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), but I'm not sure how.

Comment: modernizer.js .. google it.. :)

Comment: This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this has already been fixed in the lastest version of Bootstrap - perhaps you should just update your Bootstrap to the latest version:

- http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

(This is based on me searching the repository for $.browser and not finding anything)

Answer (score 2):

Load [Modernizr.prefixed](http://modernizr.com/docs/#prefixed) and use map helper arrays:

```
var transEndEventNames = {
    'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
    'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',
    'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd',
    'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd',
    'transition'       : 'transitionend'
},
transformHyphenateNames = {
    'WebkitTransform' : '-webkit-transform',
    'MozTransform'    : '-moz-transform',
    'OTransform'      : '-o-transform',
    'msTransform'     : '-ms-transform',
    'transform'       : 'transform'
},
transitionPropName = Modernizr.prefixed('transition'),
transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ transitionPropName ],
transformPropName = Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
transformHyphenateNames = transformHyphenateNames[ transformPropName ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option seems to be also loading [jQuery.migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) plugin.